# Sync Android with Banshee on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android, sync, banshee, mtp

I'm having a lot of trouble syncing my device (Motorola XT1080) with Banshee on Ubuntu 14.04

I've tried different ways of altering MTP options ([here](http://www.ubuntujourneyman.com/2011/05/31/sync-music-to-android-devices-with-banshee/),  [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2055563&__utma=248941774.1188052748.1406691811.1406691811.1406691811.1&__utmb=248941774.1.10.1406691811&__utmc=248941774&__utmx=-&__utmz=248941774.1406691811.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=269183986), and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702)) but nothing seems to work. The closest I got was to have the phone mount, Banshee recognized it, but then I was not able to sync any files. But, I am no longer that far in the process......

Here are some useful outputs:

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c315 Logitech, Inc. Classic Keyboard 200
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 22b8:2e66 Motorola PCS 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0007 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS451 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and the mtpfs output:

```
mtpfs

Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=22b8 and PID=2e66) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
   Found 1 device(s):
   22b8:2e66 @ bus 2, dev 7
Attempting to connect device
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02fe: get_handles_recursively(): could not get object handles.
Error 2: Error 02fe: PTP: Protocol error, data expected
Listing File Information on Device with name: (NULL)
LIBMTP_Get_Storage() failed:-1
```